# разные модальные окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

Есть плитка -> ul li.
У каждого элемента этой плитки есть свои настройки, которые можно редактировать в модальном окне. Это Название, описание и т.д.
Я сделал модальное окно. Код можно найти [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522366/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Проблема в том что открывается модальное окно первой плитки, хотя у каждой плитки есть свой html код.

Эти плитки формируются динамически - данные подгружаются из БД. У каждой плитки есть id.

Как реализовать к отдельной плитке своё модальное окно? или если возможно изменить существующее.

Часть сгенерированного кода.

```
<div class="browse-links clearfix">
    <div class="browse-links-head clearfix">
        <p>Your links</p>
        <div class="switch-view">
            <button class="grid grid-active"></button>
            <button class="list"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="links-list">
        <ul class="grid-view">
            <li>
                <div class="link-top-block">
                    <a href="account#settings" class="link-settings"></a>

                    <div id="settings" class="settings-window">
                        <form>
                            <div class="window clearfix">
                                <a href="account#close" title="Close" class="settings-close"></a>
                                <p class="settings-title">Google - Settings</p>
                                <div class="settings-main clearfix">
                                    <p class="settings-desrc-title">Link description:</p>
                                    <textarea>here desription for this link</textarea>
                                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="public-switch"
                                               class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="public-switch">
                                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="public-switch">
                                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span> <span
                                                class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                            </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="public-switch" class="switch-label">private link</label> <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <p class="switch-label-solution">you can change the access to this link</p>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="settings-delete-link" formaction="account?action=dellink&id=1" formmethod="get">Delete link</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="settings-save" formaction="account?action=savelink&id=1" formmethod="get">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="link-delete"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="link">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">Google</a>
                </div>
                <div class="link-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure do</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="link-top-block">
                    <a href="account#settings" class="link-settings"></a>

                    <div id="settings" class="settings-window">
                        <form>
                            <div class="window clearfix">
                                <a href="account#close" title="Close" class="settings-close"></a>
                                <p class="settings-title">yandex - Settings</p>
                                <div class="settings-main clearfix">
                                    <p class="settings-desrc-title">Link description:</p>
                                    <textarea>here desription for this link second</textarea>
                                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="public-switch"
                                               class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="public-switch">
                                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="public-switch">
                                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span> <span
                                                class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                            </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="public-switch" class="switch-label">private link</label> <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <p class="switch-label-solution">you can change the access to this link</p>

                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="settings-delete-link" formaction="account?action=dellink&id=1" formmethod="get">Delete link</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="settings-save" formaction="account?action=savelink&id=1" formmethod="get">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="link-delete"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="link">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">Google</a>
                </div>
                <div class="link-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure do</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* = LINKS LIST = */

.browse-links {
  width: 100% !important;
  /*height: calc(90% - 115px) !important;*/
  height: calc(100% - 158px - 40px) !important;
  position: relative !important;
  /*background-color: #1abc9c !important;*/
}
.browse-links .browse-links-head {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
.browse-links .browse-links-head p {
  width: calc(100% - 55px) !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
  min-width: 112px !important;
  float: left !important;
  background: url("../img/back-strip.png") !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list {
  width: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  height: calc(100% - 30px) !important;
}
/* View switch */

.switch-view {
  float: right !important;
}
.switch-view button.grid {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
  background: url("../img/grid-view.png");
}
.switch-view button.grid:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("../img/grid-view-hover.png") !important;
}
.switch-view button.list {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
  background: url("../img/list-view.png");
}
.switch-view button.list:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("../img/list-view-hover.png") !important;
}
.switch-view .grid-active {
  background: url("../img/grid-view-active.png") !important;
}
.switch-view .list-active {
  background: url("../img/list-view-active.png") !important;
}
/* grid-view */

.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view {
  margin: auto !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view li {
  width: 148px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  margin: 6px 4px 5px 4px !important;
  float: left !important;
  outline: 1px solid #E6E2E2 !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -o-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -o-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* list-view */

.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view {
  margin: auto !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li {
  width: 99% !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  margin: 6px 4px 5px 4px !important;
  float: left !important;
  outline: 1px solid #E6E2E2 !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -o-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: none !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li [class~="link"],
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li [class|="link"] {
  transition: none !important;
}
/* .browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li:hover { */

/*  box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */

/*  -o-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */

/*  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */

/*  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */

/* } */

/* end View switch */

/* Link block */

.link-top-block {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 24px !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
}
.link-top-block a.link-delete {
  width: 16px !important;
  height: 16px !important;
  float: right !important;
  margin: 4px !important;
  background: url("../img/link-delete.png") !important;
}
.link-top-block a.link-delete:hover {
  background: url("../img/link-delete-hover.png") !important;
}
.link-top-block a.link-settings {
  width: 16px !important;
  height: 16px !important;
  float: left !important;
  margin: 4px !important;
  background: #333 url("../img/link-settings.png") !important;
}
.link-top-block a.link-settings:hover {
  background: red url("../img/link-settings-hover.png") !important;
}
/* Settings window */

.settings-window {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in !important;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in !important;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in !important;
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
.settings-window:target {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
.settings-window form .window {
  width: 400px !important;
  max-height: 300px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  margin: 10% auto !important;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 15px !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
}
.window p.settings-title {
  padding: 3px !important;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  background: url("../img/back-strip.png") !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
.settings-desrc-title {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
.settings-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 172px;
  min-height: 172px;
  max-height: 172px;
}
.settings-main textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 4px !important;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
.settings-main .switch {
  height: 24px;
  left: 0px;
}
.settings-main p.link-status {
  float: left;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative !important;
}
.settings-main .switch-label {
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
}
.settings-main .switch-label:after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.settings-main p.switch-label-solution:before {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.settings-main p.switch-label-solution {
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative !important;
}
button.settings-delete-link {
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  top: 14px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: none;
  position: relative !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #E65252 !important;
  padding: 6px !important;
  ;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.settings-delete-link:hover {
  background: #E83131 !important;
}
.settings-close {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee url("../img/close-window.png");
}
.settings-close:hover {
  background: red url("../img/close-window-hover.png");
}
button.settings-save {
  float: right;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 9px 21px 9px 21px !important;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
  background: #1abc9c !important;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.settings-save:hover {
  background: #1ED2AF !important;
}
/* end Settings window */

.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view li .link {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: calc(100% - 24px) !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li .link {
  width: 16% !important;
  float: left !important;
  height: calc(100% - 24px) !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view li .link-description {
  display: none !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li .link-description {
  width: calc(100% - 16%) !important;
  height: calc(100% - 24px) !important;
  display: block !important;
  float: right !important;
  padding: 8px !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li .link-description p {
  font-size: 13px !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul li .link a {
  color: #333 !important;
  display: block !important;
  line-height: 56px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul li .link a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
/* end Link block */
```

```html
<div class="browse-links clearfix">
  <div class="browse-links-head clearfix">
    <p>title</p>
    <div class="switch-view">
      <button class="grid grid-active"></button>
      <button class="list"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="links-list">
    <ul class="grid-view">
      <li>
        <div class="link-top-block">
          <a href="#settings" class="link-settings"></a>

          <div id="settings" class="settings-window">
            <form>
              <div class="window clearfix">
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="settings-close"></a>
                <p class="settings-title">Google - Settings</p>
                <div class="settings-main clearfix">
                  <p class="settings-desrc-title">Link description:</p>
                  <textarea>here desription for this link</textarea>
                  <div class="onoffswitch">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="public-switch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="public-switch">
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="public-switch">
                      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <label for="public-switch" class="switch-label">private link</label>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <p class="switch-label-solution">you can change the access to this link</p>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="settings-delete-link" formaction="account?action=dellink&id=1" formmethod="get">Delete link</button>
                <button type="submit" class="settings-save" formaction="account?action=savelink&id=1" formmethod="get">Save</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="link-delete"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">Google</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-description">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure do</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="link-top-block">
          <a href="#settings" class="link-settings"></a>

          <div id="settings" class="settings-window">
            <form>
              <div class="window clearfix">
                <a href="account#close" title="Close" class="settings-close"></a>
                <p class="settings-title">yandex - Settings</p>
                <div class="settings-main clearfix">
                  <p clttings-desrc-title ">Link description:</p>
              <textarea>here desription for this link second</textarea>
              <div class="onoffswitch ">
               <input type="checkbox " name="public-switch "
                class="onoffswitch-checkbox " id="public-switch ">
               <label class="onoffswitch-label " for="public-switch ">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner "></span> <span
                class="onoffswitch-switch "></span>
               </label>
              </div>
              <label for="public-switch " class="switch-label ">private link</label> <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <p class="switch-label-solution ">you can change the access to this link</p>

             </div>
             <button type="submit " class="settings-delete-link " formaction="account?action=dellink&id=1 " formmethod="get ">Delete link</button>
             <button type="submit " class="settings-save " formaction="account?action=savelink&id=1 " formmethod="get ">Save</button>
            </div>
           </form>
          </div>
           <a href="# " class="link-delete "></a>
          </div>
          <div class="link ">
           <a href="# " target="_blank ">Google</a>
          </div>
          <div class="link-description ">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure do</p>
          </div>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <a href="#settings" class="link-settings"></a>
> <div id="settings" class="settings-window">
> ```

```
<a href="#settings-1" class="link-settings"></a>
<div id="settings-1" class="settings-window">
...
<a href="#settings-2" class="link-settings"></a>
<div id="settings-2" class="settings-window">
```

Ещё удалил лишнюю кавычку в разметке - вероятно, она там случайно оказалась.

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* = LINKS LIST = */

.browse-links {
  width: 100% !important;
  /*height: calc(90% - 115px) !important;*/
  height: calc(100% - 158px - 40px) !important;
  position: relative !important;
  /*background-color: #1abc9c !important;*/
}
.browse-links .browse-links-head {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
.browse-links .browse-links-head p {
  width: calc(100% - 55px) !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
  min-width: 112px !important;
  float: left !important;
  background: url("../img/back-strip.png") !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list {
  width: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  height: calc(100% - 30px) !important;
}
/* View switch */

.switch-view {
  float: right !important;
}
.switch-view button.grid {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
  background: url("../img/grid-view.png");
}
.switch-view button.grid:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("../img/grid-view-hover.png") !important;
}
.switch-view button.list {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
  background: url("../img/list-view.png");
}
.switch-view button.list:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("../img/list-view-hover.png") !important;
}
.switch-view .grid-active {
  background: url("../img/grid-view-active.png") !important;
}
.switch-view .list-active {
  background: url("../img/list-view-active.png") !important;
}
/* grid-view */

.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view {
  margin: auto !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view li {
  width: 148px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  margin: 6px 4px 5px 4px !important;
  float: left !important;
  outline: 1px solid #E6E2E2 !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -o-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -o-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* list-view */

.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view {
  margin: auto !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li {
  width: 99% !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  margin: 6px 4px 5px 4px !important;
  float: left !important;
  outline: 1px solid #E6E2E2 !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -o-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: none !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li [class~="link"],
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li [class|="link"] {
  transition: none !important;
}
/* .browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li:hover { */

/*  box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */

/*  -o-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */

/*  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */

/*  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */

/* } */

/* end View switch */

/* Link block */

.link-top-block {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 24px !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
}
.link-top-block a.link-delete {
  width: 16px !important;
  height: 16px !important;
  float: right !important;
  margin: 4px !important;
  background: url("../img/link-delete.png") !important;
}
.link-top-block a.link-delete:hover {
  background: url("../img/link-delete-hover.png") !important;
}
.link-top-block a.link-settings {
  width: 16px !important;
  height: 16px !important;
  float: left !important;
  margin: 4px !important;
  background: #333 url("../img/link-settings.png") !important;
}
.link-top-block a.link-settings:hover {
  background: red url("../img/link-settings-hover.png") !important;
}
/* Settings window */

.settings-window {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in !important;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in !important;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in !important;
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
.settings-window:target {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
.settings-window form .window {
  width: 400px !important;
  max-height: 300px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  margin: 10% auto !important;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 15px !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
}
.window p.settings-title {
  padding: 3px !important;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  background: url("../img/back-strip.png") !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
.settings-desrc-title {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
.settings-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 172px;
  min-height: 172px;
  max-height: 172px;
}
.settings-main textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 4px !important;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
.settings-main .switch {
  height: 24px;
  left: 0px;
}
.settings-main p.link-status {
  float: left;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative !important;
}
.settings-main .switch-label {
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
}
.settings-main .switch-label:after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.settings-main p.switch-label-solution:before {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.settings-main p.switch-label-solution {
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative !important;
}
button.settings-delete-link {
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  top: 14px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: none;
  position: relative !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #E65252 !important;
  padding: 6px !important;
  ;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.settings-delete-link:hover {
  background: #E83131 !important;
}
.settings-close {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee url("../img/close-window.png");
}
.settings-close:hover {
  background: red url("../img/close-window-hover.png");
}
button.settings-save {
  float: right;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 9px 21px 9px 21px !important;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
  background: #1abc9c !important;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.settings-save:hover {
  background: #1ED2AF !important;
}
/* end Settings window */

.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view li .link {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: calc(100% - 24px) !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li .link {
  width: 16% !important;
  float: left !important;
  height: calc(100% - 24px) !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.grid-view li .link-description {
  display: none !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li .link-description {
  width: calc(100% - 16%) !important;
  height: calc(100% - 24px) !important;
  display: block !important;
  float: right !important;
  padding: 8px !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul.list-view li .link-description p {
  font-size: 13px !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul li .link a {
  color: #333 !important;
  display: block !important;
  line-height: 56px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
.browse-links .links-list ul li .link a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
/* end Link block */
```

```html
<div class="browse-links clearfix">
  <div class="browse-links-head clearfix">
    <p>title</p>
    <div class="switch-view">
      <button class="grid grid-active"></button>
      <button class="list"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="links-list">
    <ul class="grid-view">
      <li>
        <div class="link-top-block">
          <a href="#settings-1" class="link-settings"></a>

          <div id="settings-1" class="settings-window">
            <form>
              <div class="window clearfix">
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="settings-close"></a>
                <p class="settings-title">Google - Settings</p>
                <div class="settings-main clearfix">
                  <p class="settings-desrc-title">Link description:</p>
                  <textarea>here desription for this link</textarea>
                  <div class="onoffswitch">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="public-switch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="public-switch">
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="public-switch">
                      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <label for="public-switch" class="switch-label">private link</label>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <p class="switch-label-solution">you can change the access to this link</p>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="settings-delete-link" formaction="account?action=dellink&id=1" formmethod="get">Delete link</button>
                <button type="submit" class="settings-save" formaction="account?action=savelink&id=1" formmethod="get">Save</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="link-delete"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">Google</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-description">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure do</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="link-top-block">
          <a href="#settings-2" class="link-settings"></a>

          <div id="settings-2" class="settings-window">
            <form>
              <div class="window clearfix">
                <a href="account#close" title="Close" class="settings-close"></a>
                <p class="settings-title">yandex - Settings</p>
                <div class="settings-main clearfix">
                  <p clttings-desrc-title >Link description:</p>
                  <textarea>here desription for this link second</textarea>
                  <div class="onoffswitch ">
                    <input type="checkbox " name="public-switch "
                           class="onoffswitch-checkbox " id="public-switch ">
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label " for="public-switch ">
                      <span class="onoffswitch-inner "></span> <span
                                                                     class="onoffswitch-switch "></span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <label for="public-switch " class="switch-label ">private link</label> <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <p class="switch-label-solution ">you can change the access to this link</p>

                </div>
                <button type="submit " class="settings-delete-link " formaction="account?action=dellink&id=1 " formmethod="get ">Delete link</button>
                <button type="submit " class="settings-save " formaction="account?action=savelink&id=1 " formmethod="get ">Save</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <a href="# " class="link-delete "></a>
        </div>
        <div class="link ">
          <a href="# " target="_blank ">Google</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-description ">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure do</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: где кавычка была? Спасибо. Понял.

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов, где-то, где сниппет начал неправильно раскрашивать код и сделал бредовую разметку по нажатию shift+tab.

Comment: нашел. спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов, если всё получилось, предлагаю принять ответ (зелёная галочка слева). И в [соседний вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522366/178988) загляни.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, у тебя получились совпадающие `id`.

Необходимо обеспечить уникальный признак для отображения каждого окна, продублировать код самого окна для каждой из плиток, и обеспечить показ конкретного окна по выбранному признаку.

В твоём варианте это означает уникальный якорь, в моём - отдельный input.

Comment: я подозреваю что без влияния JS никак. Для всех id я стили не пропишу...

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов, тогда индексы? Но ведь плитки ты прописал?

Comment: сами плитки прописал. и само окно с настройками тоже. Осталось сделать так что бы у каждой плитки были свои настройки в модальном окне. Что за индексы?

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов а может ты будешь стили к класам писать, а не к идентификаторам? А про индексы имеют ввиду, такой вид `id(+i)`, Т.е. каждое модальное окно будут иметь идентификаторы `id1`, `id2`... `idN`. Хотя от этого можно так же избавиться используя классы, для множеств

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев id будет браться из БД вместо со всем остальным. классы для множеств? поподробнее можно?

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов не посмотрел сначала код твоей задачи, дак и что? у тебя уникальные же идентификаторы в базе лежат? Значит в любом случае каждая кнопка будет принадлежать окну. С листом классов тут не поработаешь, ты не используешь js. Добавь в вопрос часть сгенерированного кода с модальными окнами и кнопками

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Добавил.Придётся делать модальные окна JS... наверно.

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов дак у вас один и тот же идентификатор `#settings` понятное дело что при клике открывается первое найденное окно с таким идентификатором. Задайте уникальные `иды` и все, если в базе у вас все генерируется, либо какой то название более уникальное возьмите, либо привязку, используемой  вами, типа: `#google-settings`, `#yandex-settings`. Или при генерации добавьте ключ цикла, тогда у вас каждый последующий будет `#settings1`, `#settings2`...

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов, `nth-child`. Или `+ * + * + *`. Или ещё как.

Comment: @Qwertiy и к чему это?

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов, это к: _"Что за индексы?"_

Comment: @Qwertiy не пойму как мне это поможет.

Comment: @АлександрЛемягов, сделай сниппет с нескольками плитками, где надо показывать несколько диалогов, но показывается только один.

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил в шапку. при нажатии на чёрный квадрат открывается модальное окно. Для различия - у второго модального окна должен быть заголовок отличный от первого.